# ¿Cómo verificar el error en mi analizador léxico con ply de Python?

Tags: python, c++, tokens, librería, compilador

Desde hace varios días he intenado hacer un compilador para el curso de compiladores. Decidí hacer un compilador de C++ en python, he visto algunos tutoriales y he llegado a comprender bastante. Compilo mi programa (analizador léxico) no da ningun error, pero cuando ejecuto el programa simplemente no hace nada, necesito ayuda porfavor. Les adjunto mi código.

Podrian indicarme el fallo para que pueda resolverlo, les agradecería bastante su ayuda, es primera vez que uso está página y se me fue muy recomendada, gracias desde ya chicos y chicas.

```
**import ply.lex as lex
import re
import codecs
import os
import sys 


#lista de tokens
tokens = [ 
            'IDENTIFICADOR',
            'NUMBER',
            'PARENTESIS_LEFT',
            'PARENTESIS_RIGHT',
            'LLAVE_LEFT',
            'LLAVE_RIGHT',
            'SUMA', 
            'RESTA', 
            'MULTIPLICACION', 
            'DIVISION',
            'MODULO', 
            'FIN_DE_INSTRUCCION', 
            'PUNTO_Y_COMA',
            'MAYOR_QUE',
            'MENOR_QUE',
            'MAYOR_IGUALL_QUE',
            'MENOR_IGUAL_QUE', 
            'DIFERENTE_DE', 
            'ASIGNACION', 
            'COMPARACION', 
            'AND', 
            'OR', 
            'NOT', 
            'NUMERAL',
            'COMENTARIOS_UNA_LINEA',
            'COMENTARIOS_VARIAS_LINEAS',
            'COMILLAS',
            'APOSTROFES',
            'PUNTO',
            'COMA',
            'NUMERAL',
            'MAS_MAS',
            'MENOS_MENOS',
            'MAYOR_ESCRIBIR_MOSTRAR',  #caracteres que utilizamos en C++ como cout<<
            'MENOR_OBTENER_ALMACENAR', #caracteres que utilizamos en C++ para recibir cin>>
            'ERROR'

]

#Diccionario de palabras reservadas

palabrasReservadas = {

    'include':'INCLUDE',
    'using':'USING',
    'namespace':'NAMESPACE',
    'std':'STD',
    'cout':'COUT',
    'cin':'CIN',
    'main' : 'MAIN',
    'endl':'ENDL',
    'if':'IF',
    'else':'ELSE',
    'int':'INT',
    'float':'FLOAT',
    'string':'STRING',
    'char':'CHAR',
    'bool':'BOOL',
    'const':'CONST',
    'void':'VOID',
    'do':'DO',
    'while':'WHILE',
    'for':'FOR',
    'switch':'SWITCH',
    'break':'BREAK',
    'try':'TRY',
    'catch':'CATCH',
    'return':'RETURN',
    'private':'PRIVATE',
    'public':'PUBLIC',
    'default':'DEFAULT',
    'delete':'DELETE',
    'true':'TRUE',
    'false':'FALSE'
}

#unimos el array y el diccionario

tokens = tokens + list(palabrasReservadas.values())

#DEFINIENDO CADA EXPRESION REGULAR, ESTOY EVALUANDO SU FORMATO, NO UNA COINCIDENCIA EXACTA
#EXPRESIONES REGUALES PARA SÍMBOLOS ESPECIALES DE CARACTER SIMPLE
t_ignore = '\t'
t_SUMA = r'\+'
t_RESTA = r'-'
t_MULTIPLICACION = r'\*'
t_DIVISION = r'/'
t_MODULO = r'\%'
t_ASIGNACION = r'='
t_PARENTESIS_LEFT = r'\('
t_PARENTESIS_RIGHT = r'\)'
t_LLAVE_LEFT = r'\{'
t_LLAVE_RIGHT = r'\}'
t_DOS_PUNTOS = r':'
t_PUNTO = r'\.'
t_COMA = r',' 
t_MAYOR_QUE = r'>'
t_MENOR_QUE = r'<'
t_MAYOR_IGUAL_QUE = r'>='
t_MENOR_IGUAL_QUE = r'<='
t_DIFERENTE_DE = r'!='
t_COMPARACION = r'=='
t_AND = r'\&\&'
t_OR = r'\|\|'
t_NOT = r'\!'
t_COMILLAS = r'\" '
t_APOSTROFE_LEFT = r'\''



#Definiendo expresiones regulares para caracteres ESPECIALES COMPLEJOS 
#caracteres especiales identificador, comentarios, etc 

def t_IDENTIFICADOR(t):
    r'[a-zA-Z0-9_]*' #esto es lo que reconoce un identificador
    if t.value.upper() in palabrasReservadas:
        t.value = t.value.upper()
        t.type = t.value
    return t

def t_NUMBER(t):
    r'\d+' #la d son los numeros del 1 al 9 en el lenguaje de expresiones regualares y el signo + representa que puede ir cualquier numero 1 o más veces 
    t.value = t.value #unicamente reconoce los digitos enteros
    return t

def t_FLOAT(t):
    r'\d+[^.]+\d' #reconoce numeros flotantes o decimales 
    return t

def t_STRING(t):

    r'\"?(\w+ \ *\w*\d* \ *)\"?' #expresion regular para reconocer los STRING
    return t 

def t_NUMERAL(t):
    r'\#'
    return t

def t_MAS_MAS(t):
    r'\+\+'
    return t

def t_MENOS_MENOS(t):
    r'\-\-'
    return t

def t_COMENTARIOS_UNA_LINEA(t):
    r'\/\/.*' #no devuelve un valor, reconoce que es un comentario pero obvia la función y no devuelve nada
    pass

def t_COMENTARIOS_VARIAS_LINEAS(t):
    r'\/\*\[a-zA-Z0-9_\s]*\*\/ | \*\/.*\*\/'   #no reconcoe las cadenas de caracteres de los comentarios, permite escribirlos pero los ignora
    pass #obviamos, reconoce el token pero no lo va devolver, es decir es ignorado. 


def t_FIN_DE_INSTRUCCION(t):
    r'\;'
    return t #esto es un cambio de linea 

def t_MAYOR_ESCRIBIR_MOSTRAR(t):
    r'\<\<'
    return t

def t_MENOR_OBTENER_ALMACENAR(t):
    r'\>\>'
    return t

def t_ERROR(t): #reconoce si un token es invalido

    print ("caracter ilegal '%s'") % t.value[0]
    t.lexer.skip(1)


def buscarFicheros(directorio):
    ficheros = []
    numeroArchivo = ''
    respuesta = False
    cont = 1

    for base, directorios, files in os.walk(directorio):
        ficheros.append(files)

    for file in files:  
        print (str(cont)+ ". "+ file)
        cont = cont + 1

    while respuesta == False:
        numeroArchivo = raw_input( '\n Numero de test: ')
        for file in files: 
            if file == files[int(numeroArchivo)-1]:
                respuesta == True
                break

    print ("Has escogido un archivo \" %s\" \n " %files[int(numeroArchivo)-1])

    return files[int(numeroArchivo)-1]



#ES PARA REALIZAR EL TEST

    directorio = open(r"C:\Users\Mendez Castillo\Desktop\Analizador_Lexico\Pruebas")
    archivo = buscarFicheros(directorio)
    test = directorio+archivo
    fileOpen = codecs.open(test, "r", "utf-8")
    cadena = fileOpen.read()
    fileOpen.close()

    analizadorLexico = lex.lex()
    analizadorLexico.input(cadena)

    while True:
        tok = analizadorLexico.token()
        if not tok : break
        print (tok)

input()**
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo hago en Linux (Debian 10).

Me pasaba lo mismo, prueba quitando los `**` de la importación de la librería. Al igual, te recomiendo que pongas la librería en el mismo directorio que tu compilador.

También al momento de correr el compilador yo lo hacía con `python compilador.py` y me daba error.

Así que le puse `python3 compilador.py` y me funciono!